# Meteor: Logged in user's name not showing with social login

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

When I log in to my Meteor website using email and password, `{{>loginButtons}}` displays my username:

[image: Username is showing]

```
<li id="login-dropdown-list" class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    "Yngve Høiseth"
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="login-buttons-logout">
      Logg ut
    </button>
  </div>
</li>
```

However, when I log in with Twitter or Facebook, no name is showing:

[image: Username not showing]

```
<li id="login-dropdown-list" class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="login-buttons-logout">
      Logg ut
    </button>
  </div>
</li>
```

This happens with both [accounts-ui](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-ui) and [ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3](https://atmospherejs.com/ian/accounts-ui-bootstrap-3).

I'm not doing anything fancy – just including the template. I've tried putting `{{>loginButtons}}` outside the navbar, and I've tried manually refreshing the page, to no avail.

Comment: What's the content of the `Meteor.user()` object on the client? Specifically is there a "profile.name" field for when you are logged in through Twitter or Facebook?

Comment: No, there's no `profile.name`. There's just `Object {_id: "MhEZ2G7rKSa2rGrBR"}`.

Comment: `{{> loginButtons}}` uses the `Meteor.user().profile.name` value to populate the dropdown. You may not be publishing your profile to the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there's a bit difference in `users` schema when you're using `email-password` and other third party login services. In order to display the logged is user's name , you need to create a global `users` helper and call it inside your `blaze`.

```
Meteor.users.helpers({
fullName: function () {
    if (_.has(this.services, 'facebook')) {
        return this.services.facebook.name;
    }

    if (_.has(this.services, 'google')) {
        return this.services.google.name;
    }

    return null;
}
});
```

the above code demonstrates how you can define a global helper. check out your `users` db schema and fetch the name accordingly.
then you need to call in the view like this :

```
{{ currentUser.fullName }}
```